# How can I add a Window to my Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

I created an Add-in project and now I have this in my solution explorer:

[image]

Do I just add right click the solution and add a Windows form? I'm not sure how this works and the tutorials I find don't touch on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click the project file under the solution file and select add new item.  Btw it looks like you have a missing reference for "Microsoft.CSharp though; that will need to be resolved or removed from your project.

Here is how you instantiate a form and show it in the most basic sense.

```
Form f = new Form();
f.Show();
```

Hope this helps.

Enjoy!

Comment: So I just added a Windows form, but how do I launch it from within my Add-in?

Comment: See above edit where i show the most basic way to instantiate a form and show it.